# How do I copy files inside a directory without having the folder?

Tags: batch-file, copy

I want to copy the files from the source without the directory using Batch.
(SRC -> Files) -> (Files)
When I do

```
%WINRAR%\WinRAR.exe a -afzip %BASE%\MMORPG.zip %SRC% /E
```

It copies the folder into a zip file, I just want the files, no folder.

Comment: you mean archiving into a zip file, or copying?

Comment: could you please rephrase the title to reflect your real question?

Comment: @BrandonWoolworth: Yeah, name it something like "How do I zip only the files inside a directory with WinRAR.exe?"

Answer (score 1):

Use either `-ep` or `-ep1`:

```
"%WINRAR%\WinRAR.exe" a -afzip -ep1 "%BASE%\MMORPG.zip" "%SRC%"
```

The `-ep` option strips the paths completely, while `-ep1` removes only the base path. The difference can be seen if you archive a directory containing subdirectories (and specify the `-r` option to actually include the subdirs). Since you aren't archiving subdirectories, either of these two options will do for you.

Comment: This kinda worked. Ep1 didn't but -ep did, but it took all the other folders out completely.

Comment: Yes, that's what `-ep` does. I'm a bit puzzled about why `-ep1` didn't work for you. May I ask in what way it didn't work? Perhaps, you could specify the actual command line you used.